# Installing MongoDB 2022

Tags: mongodb, installation, homebrew

I downloaded mongoDB and I try to use brew, it didn't work.
I try bunch of commands such as:

1. $ curl -O https://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.4.6.tgz
2. $ tar -zxvf mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.4.6.tgz
3. $ mkdir -p mongodb
4. $ cp -R -n mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.4.6/ mongodb
5. $ sudo mv mongodb /usr/local
   Didn't work
   Step 5: it says the directory is not empty or is not exist. I try to empty the directory didn't work and I try to create a different one, it didn't work.
   I can't find any solution. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Welcome! FYI this should be posted to SuperUser, not Stack Overflow (it's a general app installation question, not a programming question).

Answer (score 0):

I think your `/usr/local` folder already contains a non-empty folder named mongodb.

Refer [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269775/mv-directory-not-empty) for details.

You can confirm it by listing out the files in it

```
ls /usr/local/mongodb
```

Maybe, you can try removing that directory as a superuser **if it doesn't have any important files** and continue with the installation